# display monthly payment in pow(a,b) method

Tags: java

The formula to compute the monthly payment is as follows:

```
monthlyPayment = (loanAmount x monthlyInterestRate) / (1 – (1 / (1 + monthlyInterestRate)numberOfYears x 12 ))
```

In the above formula, you have to compute `(1 + monthlyInterestRate)numberOfYears x 12 )`. The `pow(a,b)` method in the `Java` API `Math class` can be used to compute ab.

so how to put this in `pow(a,b)` method ?

Comment: Some exponentiations were lost when you copied your homework question.

Comment: Please reframe you question properly bcoz result of Math.pow(a,b) is a^b example Math.pow(2,2) would be 2^2 = 4  where a^b represents a raised by b operation

Answer (score 2):

The javadoc for the [`java.lang.Math`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) class might help you here.  Is there something specific you don't understand about that?

So the code to compute the `b` power of `a` should look something like this:

```
double result = Math.pow(a, b);
```

Answer (score 0):

The formula you have does not look quite right. From [Exact_formula_for_monthly_payment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest#Exact_formula_for_monthly_payment) The formula should be

```
 P= (L i)/(1- 1/(1+i)^n )
```

Where L is the loan amount, i is the monthly interest, and n number of periods. In your formula

```
monthlyPayment = (loanAmount x monthlyInterestRate) / (1 – (1 / (1 + monthlyInterestRate)numberOfYears x 12 ))
```

the exponential sign has been missed out. I think you want

```
monthlyPayment = (loanAmount x monthlyInterestRate) / (1 – (1 / (1 + monthlyInterestRate) ^ (numberOfYears x 12) ))
```

To calculate this in java you would want

```
monthlyPayment = (loanAmount * monthlyInterestRate) / 
    (1 – (1 / Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterestRate,numberOfYears * 12)));
```

Which could be simplified to

```
monthlyPayment = (loanAmount * monthlyInterestRate) / 
    (1 – Math.pow(1 + monthlyInterestRate,-numberOfYears * 12));
```

using a negative exponent.